# Open source media player

Tags: c#, java, apache-flex, open-source, media-player

I am looking for an open-source iTunes style media player that I can use as a base for functionality I would like to develop. I am quite keen on Flex/Air, or C# or Java will do for languages.

Does anyone know of any projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Banshee](http://banshee-project.org/) uses C# and GTK#. My favorite media player

For AIR, check out [Social Media Player](http://code.google.com/p/socialmediaplayer/)

Answer (score 1):

You may check if any of the 10 media centers compared here http://telematicsfreedom.org/en/flossmediacenter might suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

http://projects.gnome.org/rhythmbox/

Sorry, only C and python.